# Unexpected difference found when comparing elements with empty elements in xmlUnit

Tags: java, xmlunit

Comparing these two snippets of XML:

```
testXml:
<ELEMENT1>
    <CHILD1></CHILD1>
</ELEMENT1>

actualXml:
<ELEMENT1>
    <CHILD1>notEmpty</CHILD1>
</ELEMENT1>
```

using:

```
Diff diff = new Diff(testXml, actualXml);
Detailed detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
```

Now `detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();` will return a `DifferenceConstants.HAS_CHILD_NODES_ID` difference and if you print the difference to the console it looks like this:

```
Expected presence of child nodes to be 'false' but was 'true' - comparing <CHILD1...> at /ELEMENT1[1]/CHILD1[1] to <CHILD1...> at /ELEMENT1[1]/CHILD1[1]
```

My question is, why is the difference of type `DifferenceConstants.HAS_CHILD_NODES_ID` and not `DifferenceConstants.TEXT_VALUE_ID`? The structure of the two XML-snippets are the same, but the text value of the two differs.

So, why doesn't that trigger a difference?

Comment: can you provide the actual xml?

Comment: This is the actual xml for a unit test that Im currently writing. So this is the exact code that I have tested.

Comment: Which ElementQualifier type are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this `ElementQualifier`:

```
Diff diff = new Diff(testXml, actualXml);
diff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier() );
Detailed detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
```

here is the description from javadoc:

> ```
> public RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier()
> ```
>
> Uses element names and the text nested an arbitrary level of child
>   elements deeper into the element to compare elements. Checks all
>   nodes, not just first child element.
>   **Does not ignore empty text nodes.**

The interested thing here is the "does not ignore empty text nodes".

It seems that the default `ElementQualifier` treats empty nodes as a missing node, and only checks for the first error related to one node. So in your case, possibly solely the "HAS_CHILD_NODES_ID" is thrown instead of including also "TEXT_VALUE_ID".

At least, `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` goes deeper.

Comment: Yes I've tried that one, but it didn't work the way I wanted just as you stated. I think I will try to implemented a DifferenceListener that ignores this case...somehow. However, it feels like there should be a cleaner way to solve this issue?